# Finding a routers setting's page that is getting internet through a local switch

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a switch that's getting shared internet, I've connected a wireless router to that switch so I can share the connection through WiFi.

AFAIK, the router isn't giving out the IPs and isn't the default gateway.

Is there a way to get the IP address of the router so that I can access the setting's page through a PC connected to that switch?

Note: Using Windows 7 in the Host.

[Network Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hS8P.jpg)

Comment: Unless you specifically disabled routing and DHCP, there is no reason it wouldnt be still routing and running DHCP.

Comment: Try to scan online IPs using IP scanner, unless you're in a work place with many devices online

Comment: @Keltari I don't think it's giving out DHCP as It's not connected through the internet port rather the normal LAN port

Comment: @Vylix I'm in a workplace, and i currently only have access to computers connected through a wired connection in the same network, but not through the wireless router

Comment: @Newbie that doesnt mean anything.  generally all routers givedhcp bby default

Comment: So let me get this straight: router -> switch -> comp. You want to connect to the switch (which *might* be a router set as switch), right? Can you wire to this "switch"?

Comment: @Keltari I couldn't connect to the router from the network, I've added a network illustration i hope that could give you a better idea, currently i'm on a wired desktop connected to the switch

Comment: @Vylix I'm connected to the switch, I wanna reach the wireless router's configuration page which I have the login credentials for

Comment: Who do you think is the DHCP server? Router or switch? Have you tried connecting to the IP of the gateway listed on your `ipconfig` ?

Comment: @Vylix I remember i tried connecting to the gateway, but it was useless

Comment: @Newbie useless as in the gateway didn't respond to ping, or it just does not respond to web admin request? Some wireless router blocks connection from wireless connection

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the router via wired interface from your laptop. The reason is - if you do not have WiFi password you can't connect through WiFi because laptops wireless card first associates with the router's SSID and only then gets IP address.

If on wired interface DHCP not working too, then look for the router's manufacturer's user guide. It will contain method how to reset router to default settings - there the IP will be known.

**As per your request** - how to discover the router's address once you are on the same subnet as the router. It means that the computer which you are running this from has **already** joined the router's wifi access point and the wireless adapter IP is set to one belonging to the router's IP subnet. Say the router's IP address is expected to be `192.168.0.1` this means it is on private C class network (see [Private Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces)) where netmask would be `255.255.255.0` or alternatively netmask is written as `/24`. So you could assign to your laptop's wifi interface any address from `192.168.0.2` to `192.168.0.254` (only the number after the third dot changes).

Then you use **[NMAP](https://nmap.org)** which is available for windows, mac and linux. The command you use is `nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24` - of course you adjust the IP address and netmask for the network to the one that you know your router and laptop are on. You get a list of all active IP addresses in that network (up to 254 for C class) together with their MAC addresses and usually the manufacturer's name. You can then narrow it down pretty quickly which is likely to be your router. Examples of manufacturers off the top of my head are `Raspberry Pi Foundation` for pis and `Arris Group` for a VirginMedia router.

As you notice - if you need to both join the router's access point (so that you are on the same wifi infrastructure) and know what the network address is, you are nearly there. If you do not know these things - that is when you may need to get the router's manual in order to factory-reset the router and then get access using the default settings. Again - easier via a cable. And reset usually will auto-enable DHCP server.

As per your illustration - you should be able to connect to the router from your PC using wired connection; it all hinges really as to what IP address the router interface has and what your PC has. If their IP's are on the same subnet - they should see each other. If you want to connect via wifi - you have first to associate with the AP then solve the problem with IP. On the other hand - you have a wifi password so the first should not be a problem. Then the typical network address ranges you can try are: `10.0.0.1 to .255 netmask 255.0.0.0, 192.168.0.1 to .255 netmask 255.255.0.0, 192.168.1.1 to .255 netmask 255.255.255.0, 172.16.0.1 .255 netmask 255.255.0.0` (see also [this](https://forums.hak5.org/index.php?/topic/18441-getting-ip-address-with-kismet/) post). So you would try setting your wifi adapter to 4 different addresses.

By far the **easier way** to learn address information is by looking at other computers that are successfully joined to the same network (either wifi or wired). On linux `ip addr list` and `ip route show`; on Windows you would go to network properties - your network adapter - connection information.

Comment: Well I do have the password, the problem is I don't know which IP it currently has in the network since it's practically a switch right now and isn't giving out any IPs, I would like to access the settings page without using a wire because the router is hard to access physically, Everytime i need to change the settings would be a major problem

Comment: I can tell you how to use `nmap` to find the router's IP address but you need to have IP address on your network card (either wired or wifi) to be able to _reach_ that router in the first place. So you must know the network address to give to your laptop - such as `192.168.0.2/255.255.255.0` if you need an explanation what those numbers mean that also could be a start to solving your problem.

Comment: well, can you give me a tutorial on how to pull it off?